# Выделять ли запятыми одиночное деепричастие "прибыв"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия

> Прибыв(,) он увидел ужасную картину — миллионы воинов, испепеленных заживо ...

Нужна ли запятая?

Comment: А что, отредактировать сложно? Вопрос ясный: нужна ли запятая в предложении?

Comment: @Jasmin Так исправьте вопрос и голосуйте за его переоткрытие.

Comment: Я же  не редактор, их и без меня много.  Вы сами говорили. что пока один  исправляет текст,  другой уже исправляет исправленное.

Comment: ОК, я отредактировал вопрос. Призываю голосовать за его переотркрытие.

Comment: @Jasmin прошу вас: редактируйте вопрос, даже когда его уже редактирует другой участник с самого дальнего конца света, и голосуйте за переоткрытие. Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь, – ведь от этого никому не лучше.

Comment: Хорошо, не буду стесняться. Я просто думала, что редактор - это должность такая.

Answer (score 1):

**Прибыв, он увидел ужасную картину — миллионы воинов, испепеленных заживо ...**

Для начала рассмотрим у**же предложенные варианты решения.**

1) **Одиночное деепричастие обособляется, если сохраняет значение действия?** А как узнать, что оно его сохраняет?

2) **Одиночное деепричастие обособляется, если указывает  на время действия, его причину, условие и т. д. (но не на образ действия).** Ну не всегда, хотя это и цитата из Розенталя, но тот же Розенталь ниже приводит такие примеры: *Она будила сына улыбаясь. Улыбаясь, она разбудила сына. Погрузился в мысли, улыбаясь. Говорил улыбаясь* (‘с улыбкой’).  Здесь у деепричастия или значение второго действия (обособляется), или значение обстоятельства образа действия (не обособляется), но в обоих случаях оно отвечает на вопрос КАК.

Как же решаются такие задачи? Здесь надо провести **грамматический и, что очень важно, структурно-интонационный анализ.**

1) **Деепричастия и нераспространенные деепричастные обороты не обособляются при наличии следующих признаков:**

а) обозначают признак действия и играют  роль обстоятельства образа действия в основном сообщении;

б) можно заменить **наречием-синонимом**;

в) часто находятся в конце  предложения, являясь при этом центром высказывания (на деепричастие падает логическое ударение);

г) обычно (но не всегда)   не обособляются деепричастия несовершенного вида.

2) **Деепричастия и нераспространенные деепричастные обороты  *обособляются* при наличии следующих признаков:**

а) обстоятельство обозначает добавочное действие, а не признак основного действия;

б) является аналогом придаточного предложения, отвечает на соответствующие вопросы;

в) удобная для обособления позиция деепричастия, например между подлежащим и сказуемым или в начале предложения.

**Решение**

**ПрибЫв, он увидел ужасную картИну...**

Деепричастие совершенного вида, находится в начале предложения, обозначает второе действие и является аналогом придаточного времени ( *когда он прибыл)*.

С одной стороны, каждый из этих признаков не гарантирует обособление, например: *Князь шёл задумавшись* (сов. вид). *Не торопясь* (= неторопливо) *я спустился к оврагу* (начало предложения).  Однако в целом они могут помочь в принятии верного решения.

**И вывод.**  Необособленное  деепричастный оборот  **должен соответствовать  наречию по всем показателям**: как по семантике, так и по характерной позиции обстоятельства   в предложении, в противном случае он обособляется.  Поверить правильность принятого решения можно **с помощью интонации.**

**Примечание.** Интересно то, что в данном примере деепричастие можно заменить необособленным наречием-детерминантом, отнесенным ко всему предложению: *По прибытии он увидел ужасную картину..*. Получается, что самую важную роль здесь играет интонация. Собственно говоря, с нее и можно было начинать анализ, получив таким образом уже готовое решение.

Answer (score 0):

**Прибыв, он увидел ужасную картину...**

Прибыв — одиночное деепричастие. Оно должно обособляться.

[ДЕЕПРИЧАСТНЫЕ КОНСТРУКЦИИ](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113)

> Одиночное деепричастие обособляется, если сохраняет значение глагольности, выступая в функции второстепенного сказуемого, указывая на время действия, его причину, условие и т. д. (но не на образ действия)

В нашем случае деепричастие указывает на время действия (когда он увидел ужасную картину?). Дополнительная причина для обособления деепричастия - оно расположено в начале предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Выделять. Одиночные деепричастия обособляются при сохранении ими глагольного значения — обозначении действия:
*Заскрежетав, закрылись двери* (Вороб.). [Двери заскрежетали и закрылись.]

*Приехав, он просидел около часу у могильной ограды, положив тяжелую руку в шерстяной перчатке на обжигающий сквозь шерсть чугун...* (В. Набоков)
[Он приехал и просидел...]

*Приехав, они увидели, что Брэдли лежит в луже крови, а из спины...* (И. Мельников)
[Они приехали и увидели...]

[Знаки препинания при обособленных обстоятельствах. § 70](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121)